# OpenAMのAD連携について

Tags: apache, tomcat, openssl, openldap

OpenAMでAD連携してユーザーを取り込みました
AD連携したユーザーでOpenAMにログインする
ユーザーごとに権限を付与する為にはどういった項目を設定すればよいでしょうか

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

AD連携したユーザーでOpenAMにログインすると以下のメッセージが表示される
「このユーザーはアクティブではありません」となる

ADで取り込んだユーザーに対して何をしたらよいのかわからない

#### 試したこと

OpenAMのPolicyをAD連携で取り込んだユーザーに適用させた

OpenAMにAD連携したユーザーと同じIDをOpenAMに作成するとユーザーに権限を付けることができ、
OpenAMにログインも可能となった

#### 補足情報

OpenAM 13.5

Answer (score 0):

「このユーザーはアクティブではありません」のメッセージが表示されるときは、ユーザーの属性「ユーザー状態」が「非アクティブ」になっている時です。まずは以下を試してみて下さい。

1. OpenAMの管理コンソールにamadminでログイン
2. アクセス制御 > (ユーザーが登録されているレルム) > 対象 のタブをクリックし、該当ユーザーのプロファイルページを表示
3. 「ユーザー状態」を「非アクティブ」から「アクティブ」に変更

Comment: ご回答どうもありがとうございます。該当ユーザーの設定画面を確認したところ、「アクティブ」にチェックされている状態でした。引き続きお気づきの点ありましたらご指摘お願いいたします

Comment: であるとすれば、インメモリーアカウントロックが効いてるかもしれません。一度OpenAMを再起動して動作確認したら、どうなりますかね？

Comment: それから確認ですが、「AD連携」として具体的にどのような設定をしたのでしょうか？WindowsデスクトップSSOなのか、AD認証モジュールなのか、とか簡単に設定内容も質問に追記していただけないでしょうか。